# Checking if the touchscreen is resistive or capacitive

Tags: windows, windows-10, asus-laptop, touchscreen

I'd like to know if there is a way to check if the display of my laptop (ASUS N550JK-CM097H with Windows 10), which is touch, is a resistive or a capacitive touchscreen.

Comment: It's capacitive, no need to test but if you want you can do the usual stuff: Use a plastic object to press, if it works then resistive (it isn't).

Comment: Addition to @ChanganAuto comment: If you touch with your finger *covered* by thin plastic, e.g., plastic glove or plastic bag, and it still works, it's capacitive, otherwise, resistive. Plastic alone, e.g., a plastic spoon held at the other end, will not activate *either*. BTW, there are also ultrasonic touch screens and infrared touch screens, though I don't know of any laptop maker using them now. They're useful in adverse environments, such as underwater.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanations

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER**

If you can "pinch" (i.e. the machine can register more than one touch screen at a time), it is **capacitive**, otherwise it is **resistive**.

**LONGER ANSWER**

According to [Geeks for geeks](https://%20https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-touch-screen-technology/), there are four types of touch screen technologies the ones used in laptops being Resistive and Capacitive.

The Resistive Touch Screen are reliable and durable but  can handle only one touch at a time; while the  Capacitive Touch Screen (which exist in two types, projective and surface) are more fragile but manage multi touch.